# Анализ php-кода на совместимость с php 5.2.4

Tags: php

Где найти анализатор кода на совместимость с php 5.2.4?

5.3-7.2 встроены в PhpStorm. Ниже нет. Онлайн смог найти только 5.2.17.

Comment: http://php.net/releases/

Comment: Это описание. Я его знаю. Мне нужен автоматический анализатор кода.

Comment: `5.2.4`, уххх... Как ты хоть с таким столкнулся. Динозаврикам привет там передай от меня :D

Comment: @Manitikyl WordPress работает на 5.2.4 - 7.2. Есть заказчики, которые требуют того же от разработчиков плагинов.

Comment: Мне кажется у них в пуле плагинов не все 100% совместимы с `5.2.4`, а писать под ту версию, на которую скорей не перейдешь - выйдет дороже (по ресурсам). Но хозяин-барин ;) Удачи с плагином

Comment: Согласно правилам официального репозитория WordPress, плагины не обязаны быть совместимыми с определённой версией php. Хоть 7.2, не вопрос. У меня другая история.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оказывается, всё просто.

Загрузить из архивов php 5.2.4 на локальный компьютер. Запустить линтер (анализатор кода)

```
php -l файл.php
```

Comment: У меня нубский вопрос: линтер доступен и для линукс, и для виндовс?

Comment: @Эдуард да, конечно